# Does `import()` resolve when the module is fully parsed?

Tags: javascript, dynamic-import

Using the dynamic `import()` syntax, I can load a module at runtime, e.g.

```
if (someCondition) await import('some-other-file');
```

Is it safe to assume that, once that promise resolves, `some-other-file` has been fully parsed, and any synchronous side-effects it triggers will have happened already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is the actual behavior, as written in [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#import_a_module_for_its_side_effects_only)

Demo with a data URL:

```js
const code = "window.foo = 'bar';";
const importString = `data:application/javascript;charset=utf-8;base64,${btoa(code)}`;

import(importString).then(() => console.log(foo))
```